# Solve $T(n) = T( \lfloor 2n / 10\rfloor ) + \Theta(n^3)$ recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

I don't know how to solve the following recurrence. Particularly, I don't know how to cope with the $2n$ term:
$$T(n) = T( \lfloor 2n / 10\rfloor ) + \Theta(n^3)$$

Master theorem of recurrences doesn't really explains how to... I was thinking that this would solve it:

$$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n / 10\rfloor) + \Theta(n^3)$$

But I'm not sure. How do I approach this?

Comment: Im doing that but i added just in case it was necessary. But thanks, i didnt know about that. I was doing it blindly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

\begin{align}T(n) &= T(\lfloor2n/10 \rfloor) + \Theta(n^3) \\
&= T(\lfloor n/5\rfloor) + \Theta(n^3) &(1)\\
&=T(n/5) + \Theta(n^3) & (2)\\
&= \Theta(n^3) & (3)\end{align}

I have applied:

$(1)$ Fraction simplification: $2n/10 = n/5$.

$(2)$ Removing floors. In general you can remove all floors and ceilings in recurrences that may be solved with the master theorem, that is, recurrences of the form $$T(n) = a T(n/b) + g(n)$$ (this is a proved fact).

$(3)$ Application of the master theorem.

Comment: I was confused here $=T(⌊n/5⌋)+Θ(n3)$ , so i just simplify ? Dividing by 2?

Comment: Hey, if you can just tell me.. What should i do if it would be a number that i cant simplify, like $T(N) = T(3n/10) + \Theta(n^3) $ ?

Comment: In general $$n\frac{a}{b} = \frac{n}{b/a},$$ so $3n/10 = n / (10/3)$. Just think it as "we divide our $n$ size problem into a $10/3$ size problem".

Comment: Thanks it helped me understand it! I voted UP but it wont compute until i  get enough reputation. I dont know why someone voted down.

Comment: Maybe he didn't want you to give the answer. However, You didnt do anything wrong because i do know how to calculate using the master theorem and as you helped me on the "edit" propostal, my problem was related to the "2n term".